# Android Studio | Save Layouts permanently

Tags: java, android

I have a question about saving data locally.
When I press a button on my UI, the program generates a `FrameLayout` with some checkboxes and `TextViews`. I want to save these Layout Constructions permanently, but all my solutions failed. When I search for that in the web, I only find solutions for saving simple `Strings` or numbers.
I would appreciate for some solutions

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are not meant to be persisted. They have to be recreated on every application launch.

You can define layouts in xml, and inflate them every time. That is probably closest to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [F43nd1r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4388512/f43nd1r), if you want to after a relaunch of your app goes to an specific layout, what you need to do it's save the state of your app on the local database (using SQLite, Realm, etc) , and when relaunch, load this configs from the local database and inflate the xml layouts based on this configs.